# Animating single component using transition vue-js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

When I try to use the vue component - 'transition' that allows me to animate the appearance and disappearance of an element, I encountered that the editor (Web Storm) refuses to accept this component, describing it by the fact that the component does not exist (Unknown html tag transition). How to make tag - 'transition' available?

```
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Переключить
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})


.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active до версии 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0
}
```

Comment: Did you try this. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/vue-js.html

Comment: Try install this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9442-vue-js